# How to extract only a part of "For Each" loop in ASP/VBScript

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, asp-classic

I was using this code to extract all items in a RSS file.

```
For Each item In r.items.items
    response.write(item.title)
Next
```

Each RSS file have 100 items and now I want to show only child numbers from 10 to 20. I dont know how to extract exact items. I have tried the following code:

```
For x = 10 To 20
    response.write(r.items.items(x).title)
Next
```

but I got an error:

> Object not a collection: 'items'

Comment: How are you parsing the RSS file? You using a library or doing the XML parse yourself? Can you show a sample of the RSS? This isn't a lot to go off to be honest. Used plenty of ASP scripts / classes to parse RSS but don’t recognise this one.

Comment: this is the library I use: http://www.webdevbros.net/2007/07/01/asp-vbscript-rss-readerwriter-class/#comment-4500 @Lankymart

Comment: It’s clear from the documentation that the `Items` property of the `RSS` class is a `Scripting.Dictionary` object of `RSSItem` class objects so [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57140764/692942) is correct.

Comment: The `Items()` call is a method that returns an array, so you could just do `Call Response.Write(r.items.items()(x).title)`, but it's better to create the array and store it once. See [Items Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//8aet97f2%28v%3dvs.85%29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the type of `r.items.items`. I'd suspect that it's enumerable, but doesn't allow indexed access to its elements. You can work around that by using a `For Each` loop with a custom counter.

```vb
i = 0
For Each item In r.items.items
    If i > 20 Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf i >= 10 Then
        response.write(item.title)
    End If
    i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: This is correct `Items` is a `Scripting.Dictionary` according to the documentation.